# Get DLL name from Window Handle

Tags: .net, vb.net, pinvoke

Ok I'm a bit unsure about this one so let me ask the question here.

Having searched online I found a few examples of how to find the EXE name from a Window Handle, but that's not what I'm after.

Imagine the scenario:
An Executable has references to a DLL, call it MyLittleDLL.dll
This DLL contains a number of windows. So the .exe calls some method in the .dll and the .dll shows a window to the user.

Now - The DLL is actually an Outlook Add-in we wrote. And MyLittleDLL.dll is our DLL.

Another .exe instantiates a new Outlook.Inspector and it shows a form from our DLL. I am getting all the child windows from the Inspector. These could come from OUR dll or from any other Add-in's Form Regions. Obviously I don't want to mess with *those*, so as I go through the list of child window handles I want to establish whether it's "one of ours" before sending any messages to it.

So the question is:
**given a hWnd (IntPtr), is there a way I can establish that this hWnd belongs to MyLittleDLL.dll - in other words - can I get the owning Assembly Name from a hWnd**?

I code in VB.NET but C# examples are no problem.

Comment: Binaries don't contain nor own windows. Windows are created by a piece of code that runs in a specific process (hence the relation between a process and all the Windows it has created). What you can do is add your own information to the Windows you create. For example, you can use SetWindowLong (need to interop) with the GWL_USERDATA field: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga and read it back using GetWindowLong

Comment: Not a real problem.  "sending any messages to it" requires knowing the window handle.  You already know it since you created it, you can't accidentally send it to another window or "region".  Where the code lives doesn't matter.

Comment: @HansPassant: OP also has the handle of *other* windows: *"[...] I am getting all the child windows from the Inspector. These could come from OUR dll or from any other Add-in's Form Regions. [...]"* And the process sending the messages is not the process creating the window: *"Another .exe instantiates a new Outlook.Inspector [...]"*

Comment: Thanks Heinzi - Exactly. I perform a "CreateItem" on the Outlook.Application and then I activate its Inspector. That gives me the Window Handle of the INSPECTOR. All I know is that ONE of the Child Windows of that Inspector Window is for the Region that contains the Form for my Add-in. So I am trying to figure out which of the 93 child windows is the one that I need to Send the Message to.

Comment: Ok I will leave this open in case anybody has an actual answer to this which may then help somebody else. In the meantime, however, I found a different solution through the Outlook.Application.COMAddIns through which I could get an Object pointing at my Add-in Form Region and from there I could then directly access a Method on that object. Problem solved. But maybe some day somebody else won't have the luxury of being able to take an alternative approach...

Comment: You can also get a Window when it's opened using UI Automation (registering a `WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent` event handler). The Window `AutomationElement` references the `ProcessID` that owns it. Depending on what kind of process is this (I don't know which process owns the Window in your scenario), you could get `Process.GetProcessById(windowElement.ProcessId).MainModule.ModuleName` (or get the list of `[Process].Modules` and check whether it contains yours).